# Stored procedure MySQL-- Membership discount by number of orders placed

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a stored procedure and according to the number of orders, the customer placed they will get a specific discount.

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
  cust_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  fname varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  lname varchar(50) NULL,
  DOB date NULL,
  email varchar(50) NULL,
  phone varchar(15) NULL,
  home_addr varchar(200) NULL,
  password varchar(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (cust_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE cust_order (
  cust_order_ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  cust_order_date datetime NOT NULL,
  cust_order_status varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  cust_order_price numeric (5,2) NOT NULL,
  charge_date_time datetime NOT NULL,
  cust_ID int NOT NULL,
  shipping_ID int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (cust_order_ID),
  FOREIGN KEY (cust_ID) REFERENCES customer (cust_ID), 
  FOREIGN KEY (shipping_ID) REFERENCES shipment (shipping_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE cust_membership (
  membership_ID int NOT NULL,
  start_date date NOT NULL,
  end_date date,
  cust_ID int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (membership_ID, cust_ID), 
  FOREIGN KEY (membership_ID) REFERENCES membership (membership_ID), 
  FOREIGN KEY (cust_ID) REFERENCES customer (cust_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE membership (
  membership_ID int NOT NULL,
  memb_name  varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  discount_value numeric(5,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (membership_ID)
);

-- STORED PROCEDURE---

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetMembershipDiscountByOrdersPlaced (IN cust_email varchar(50), OUT cust_memb_name varchar(50), OUT new_order_cost numeric(5,2))
  BEGIN

DECLARE new_order_cost numeric(5,2) DEFAULT 0.00;


SELECT COUNT(*) INTO total_orders 
FROM customer NATURAL JOIN cust_order
WHERE email = cust_email;

SELECT cust_order_price INTO cur_order_cost
FROM customer NATURAL JOIN cust_order
WHERE email = cust_email
ORDER BY cust_order_date DESC
LIMIT 1;


IF total_orders<=15 THEN
    SET new_order_cost = cur_order_cost - (cur_order_cost * 0.05)
    SELECT "Bronze" INTO cust_memb_name;
ELSE 
    IF total_orders<40 THEN
      SET new_order_cost = cur_order_cost - (cur_order_cost * 0.10)
      SELECT "Silver" INTO cust_memb_name;
    ELSE 
      SET new_order_cost = cur_order_cost - (cur_order_cost * 0.15)
      SELECT "Golden" INTO cust_memb_name;
    END IF;
END IF;


  END// 
DELIMITER ;
```

Could you please assist me?

Comment: Can you please clarify what is exactly the issue in here?

Comment: Please format the query, the code `{}` button in the editing. Formatted `CREATE TABLE` to be [readable would be nice too](http://sqlformat.org/).

Comment: `NATURAL JOIN` should be avoided always. You'll add a column later and your code will generate a different result. Why are you doing a stored procedure at all.

Comment: My apologies to all. I should have been more clear. I have an assignment and the lecturer asked us to create a database etc. He also asked us to create stored procedures...so I have created an online database and some of the tables are the 'customer' table, 'cust_order' table, 'cust_membership' table and the 'membership' table. A customer can have one and only membership such as Bronze, Silver and Golden. Each membership comes with a discount value and I wanted that discount value to be applied to their final order cost.

Comment: @danblack, Thank you for your response:) I wish I did not have to make any store procedure... its the lecturer that want us to...:/ anyhow, he insists that we use natural joins... All is for the purpose of the course.

Comment: I've wondered why SO is so full of people insisting on writing stored procedures. Its kinda crazy, like `NATURAL JOINS`. Please move past it once you complete your course.

Comment: @danblack, haha my head is all over the place...